# In Distributed Tensorflow, what is the effect of having multiple parameter servers?

Tags: tensorflow, parameters, parallel-processing, distributed

When we have a parameter server which is updated by its workers, what is the effect of having multiple parameter servers for the same number of workers?

i.e. what happens when we have multiple parameter servers instead of one parameter server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as having multiple parameter server shards. This gives some more details
https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/large_deep_networks_nips2012.pdf, especially section 4.1

> To apply SGD to large data sets, we introduce Downpour SGD, a variant
>   of asynchronous stochastic gradient descent that uses multiple
>   replicas of a single DistBelief model. The basic approach is as
>   follows: We divide the training data into a number of subsets and run
>   a copy of the model on each of these subsets. The models communicate
>   updates through a centralized parameter server, which keeps the
>   current state of all parameters for the model, sharded across many
>   machines (e.g., if we have 10 parameter server shards, each shard is
>   responsible for storing and applying updates to 1/10th of the model
>   parameters) (Figure 2)